# String Column Data is getting persisted as Null from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate to persist an entity. But the data is getting persisted as null, even though when the entity contains the specified field value.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("example")
public class Controller {

@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

@RequestMapping("/getData")
@Transactional
public void getData() {

    Members member = new Members();
    member.firstName= "SRC";
    member.lastName = "Code";
    member.major = "Computer Science";
    member.ID = 424;

    entityManager.persist(member);
}
```

Members class

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "members")
    public class Members {


    @Id
    public int ID;
    public String major;

    @Column(name = "firstName" , nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 0, max =20)
    public String firstName;


    @Length(min = 0, max =20)
    @Column(name = "lastName" , nullable = false)
    public String lastName;
}
```

But the data in the database table is getting null values for firstName and `LastName fields. But the ID and major is correctly persisted.`

Comment: Do not use public member variables. Make them `private` and use `getter` and `setter`

Comment: if something is persisted, then look in the log of your chosen JPA provider at the SQL invoked. aka "debugging"

Comment: Impossible to know what is wrong with the info provided, but some general remarks: 1) Use `Member` as class name, not `Members`
2) Use `id` for your primary key name in Java, not `ID`
3) Don't do database updates on a GET request

Comment: @WimDeblauwe This was a sample code just to try out things. Used Members as class name , since the name of the table in my DB is members. 
Not sure why this is not working for 2 fields.

Comment: You might want to [enable logging of Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate) to get more information.