# Why spring data parameter of type List does not printed on log like other parameters type?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

in my spring boot app I am using these configs:

```
  logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
   logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

to print hibernate query and then the parameters values.

```
@Query( value="select h from Human h inner join com.human.Card c on c.humanId = h.id where h.card.status in :statuses " )
Page<Human> getHumanByStatus(@Param(statuses) List<Status>, Pageable pageable);
```

int the log the query printed without the list values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding following, Nothing more.

**aplication.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type: TRACE
```

**aplication.properties**

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Also you can refer to this more options: [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Comment: @AbdullahRamdan could you please accept & upvote answer, if it helped you.