# Is it possible to see Hibernates logging as SQL code?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My question is very general,
When Hibernate logging is set to true, we can see what Hibernate writes inside the console as some sort of Hibernate SQL language.

Is it possible to translate this, or even get it in the console as regular SQL code? 
So it would say something like
INSERT product('name', 'price') WHERE.. etc..

Instead of the Hibernate language we currently see. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: To clarify, I would like to copy what Hibernate writes in my console, and be able to paste it into my SQL Workbench and insert it as an SQL command. (IF this is possible that is.) Thanks!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Comment: SQL logging with params bound: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/1356423

Comment: This only allows for us to see it in an SQL way? But is it possible to see it in a way so I could copy the entire statement over to a SQL file and use it inside of my workbench?

Comment: The answer referred to in my 2nd comment outputs the actual SQLstatements  executed by Hibernate to the console or file depending on your logging set up. I'm not sure exactly what else you would need.

Comment: It logs like this for me:
        */ insert 
        into
            question
            (mandatory, position, question_type, title) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)

WIth the values being printed above it, it's not possible to have it not do the questionmarks at all and instead show the values inserted?

Comment: As I have pointed out - **TWICE** - I have given an answer here -  stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/1356423 -  that will log the SQL **with the parameters in place**.