# Need to verify the parameters passed by hibernate to the sql query

Tags: hibernate, logging, spring-data-jpa, error-logging

I need to check the query created by the *hibernate* and the parameters passed in the query by *hibernate*.
I am using `application.yml` file for configuration and `logback.xml` for logging.

I have added

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"/>
```

property in the `logback.xml` and

```
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

in `application.yml` file.

the property show-sql :true works fine and I am able to see the query generated by JPA

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ply_blackhole_entity_mapping 
    where
        detail_id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ply_vms_provider_blackhole_restriction 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ply_blackhole_detail 
    where
        id=?
```

but I am not able to see the parameters passed to it.

Comment: Are you not seeing `o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter` , just after the query line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)