# Hibernate Why setParameter for a concatenate string in the IN Clause not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I do some research but have no satisfied answer yet.
I have a table, and it supposed to have 3 records if I run it under a database management system like navicat.

```
____
id  |
____    
1   |
2   |
3   |
```

If I using set parameter with a concatenate string, it will return just the 1st value

```java
List<Integer> here = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (:here)");
query.setParameter("here", StringUtils.join(here, ","));
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
query.list();
```

but if I use `setParameterList`, it will return all values:

```java
List<Integer> here = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (:here)");
query.setParameterList("here", here );
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
query.list();
```

I did debug it to see the real sql, but I see no problem in the 1st case

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ 
    SELECT 
         * 
    FROM 
         table 
    WHERE 
         id IN (
               ?
         )
HibernateLog --> TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [1,2,3]
TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [1,2,3]
```

Can someone deep explain why the 1st case not working? I am using mysql.

EDIT:

Thanks for all the suggestions. After i used log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1 and logged the sql out (before hibernate send it to database):

```
DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly -  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
500. SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')

16:19:33.518 [http-nio-8280-exec-4] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable - 
|---|
|id |
|---|
|1  |
|---|
```

Anyone want to log the full sql before it goes to db can see this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/4181109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected since hibernate is detecting types to build your query and you send a string instead of a list. The second method is explicitly telling it to expect a list.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the root cause of this behaviour is MySql [type conversion in expression evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).

MySql try to convert passed to the `expr IN (value,...)` value '1,2,3' to DOUBLE type (see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)) and as result you actually get:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1)
```

when you run this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')
```

and mysql also generate the following warning:

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,2,3'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i did found out that hibernate did convert the sql into 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('1,2,3'); before sending it into mysql

Comment: In fact, this is not transformation, hibernate generate exactly the same query as you ask, but then mysql transform the `'1,2,3'` value to `1`  and this behaviour can be unexpected as mentioned in the mysql documentation.