# Change logging level to print actual values from query that uses Indexed parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, logging, spring-data-jpa

Im using Indexed parameters to pass values into native query JPA. How to change logging so I can see the actual values passed into query printed in the console? Currently values are not shown, only `?`:

```
org.hibernate.SQL : select * from car_records where carVinNo = ?
```

query

```
   public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select * from car_records where carVinNo >= ?1")
   }
   List<Car> retrieveCars(Long startRegTs);
```

I tried to config yml as suggested in other posts but nothing works so far.

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type: TRACE
```

Comment: Logging won't replace the question marks, it will log the values in separate log messages (i.e. lines in typical configurations)

Comment: This really seems like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate but I'm leaving it open since you seem to already apply that solution, so the mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: Thats what Im looking for. The values should be printed somewhere in the console.

Comment: if you use the logging framework to write a log message to `org.hibernate.type`, does it get logged out? Can you put a break point where hibernate logs these values and step into the logging framework code to see where and why it does get discarded?