# How can I view Hibernate queries in MySQL syntax in console?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, properties

Now I'm displaying them like this after adding the format_sql = true property. But I would like to be able to view them with the classic query that I would see for example in MySQL Workbranch. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gLXl.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but it sure is a good and useful compromise

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Tools has a feature that converts [HQL into SQL](https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html#hql-editor): https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/

Comment: Too bad it's only for Eclipse not IntelliJ, thanks anyway

Comment: OK, but you should specify that you need it for IntelliJ