# CrudRepository save() throws "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction"

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have an error during an update transaction on my database using JpaRepository. I saw that there are many questions about this same error here but none of the solutions mentioned seem to solve my case. This is my main method:

```
 public View update(Long productCode, Long customerCode, UpdateForm form) {

        var entityToUpdate = repository.findByProductCodeAndCustomerCode(productCode, customerCode);

        var updatedObject = new Builder(entityToUpdate).build(form);
        var savedObject = repository.save(updatedObject); //error thrown here

        return converter.convertToView(savedObject);
    }
```

This is the Builder class implementation that appears above:

```
    public class Builder {

    private final Purchase entityToUpdate;

    public Builder(Optional<Purchase> entityToUpdate) {
        this.entityToUpdate = entityToUpdate.isPresent() ? entityToUpdate.get() : null;
    }

    public Purchase build(PurchaseUpdateForm form) {

        this.entityToUpdate.setDiscount(form.getDiscount());
        this.entityToUpdate.getId().setPurchaseBoxQuantity(form.getPurchaseBoxQuantity());

        return entityToUpdate;
    }
}
```

I tried to put an `@Transactional` in the `update()` and `build()` methods but the error persists. I also tried using `saveAndFlush` but nothing changed. Full log message:

```
Optimistic locking failed; nested exception is caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: 
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): 
[PurchasePK@bb7039e8]
```

**# Additional Information - Domain**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_PURCHASE")
public class Purchase {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private PurchasePK id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT")
    private BigDecimal discount;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "product", "purchaseBoxQuantity" })
@Embeddable
public class PurchasePK {
    
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_PRODUCT")
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_CUSTOMER")
    private Product product;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "QT_BOXES")
    private Long purchaseBoxQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing means Hibernate tried to update an entity, but the update statement actually updated 0 rows.

Hibernate assumes this is because the version attribute did not match, since for the purpose of optimistic locking all updates on entities with a version attribute have a where clause like the following.

```sql
WHERE id = ? and version = ?
```

The `id = ?` ensures that the correct row is updated. The `version = ?` ensures that the version hasn't changed. It does get changed with every update.

Since you don't have a version attribute in your entity, I'm somewhat surprised that you still get this error, but since you do, the only explanation is that the `id` does not match the one in the database.

So either the entity was deleted, or the id changed.

- Make sure the id didn't get changed by accident.
- Make sure the id gets passed to the database as expected. You can do that by [enabling logging of SQL statements and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Without having the full source, I can just guess that the problem is on your embedded id, specifically I guess it has to be with

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I suggest you to add the following properties to your application properties file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

so you can check how your entity's id is probably changed in a way you didn't expect to.