# Logback configuration to filter by message

Tags: java, logging, logback, spring-logback

Is possible to add a filter by message in my logback config?

I am using a tool which logs the SQL statements generated by Hibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/5033118

I overwrite the logback configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="ERROR" />

    <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="ERROR" />

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The tool logs the statements, but it also logs some other messages:

```
1. PreparedStatement.new PreparedStatement returned 
1. Connection.prepareStatement(delete from AIXM_FEATURE_EVENT_MAPPING where TS_ID=?) returned net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.PreparedStatementSpy@4aab04cf
1. PreparedStatement.setString(1, "3b855115-2da2-495c-a3bf-b2328916ef77") returned 
1. delete from AIXM_FEATURE_EVENT_MAPPING where TS_ID='3b855115-2da2-495c-a3bf-b2328916ef77'  {executed in 38 ms}
1. PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() returned 0
1. PreparedStatement.getMaxRows() returned 0
1. PreparedStatement.getQueryTimeout() returned 0
1. PreparedStatement.close() returned
```

What I am trying to do is to add a filter in my logback configuration to get ONLY the SQL statements (and to format them if possible - remove the "1. " from the start of the line and add a ";" at the end).

```
delete from AIXM_FEATURE_EVENT_MAPPING where TS_ID='3b855115-2da2-495c-a3bf-b2328916ef77';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `jdbc.sqlonly` for record sql, and turn off all below props since you
need sql only `jdbc.sqltiming jdbc.audit jdbc.resultset jdbc.connection`.

How to turn on/off, you could see this from [official github link](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc/blob/master/doc/log4j.xml)