Spring boot: @Query and @Param don't work as i think
I am learning spring boot and trying to connect to mysql. I write a simple sql query using @Query and @Param. Below is my query.
@Repository
public interface UnitRepository extends JpaRepository<Unit, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM unit u WHERE u.id=:id AND u.display_name=:displayName", 
  nativeQuery = true)
  List<Unit> getByFilter(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("displayName") String displayName);
}

And then i use getByFilter in another:
public List<Unit> getByFilter(Long id, String displayName) {
    System.out.println(displayName);
    return unitRepository.getByFilter(id, displayName);
  }

When i test with id=0 and displayName=kilogram, i expect the query is SELECT * FROM unit u WHERE u.id=0 AND u.display_name=kilogram but actually it is SELECT * FROM unit u WHERE u.id=? AND u.display_name=?.
Below is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
        </dependency> 
        <!-- MySQL dependency -->
        <dependency> 
                <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
                <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
                <scope>test</scope> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


How can i figure out my problem??
I tried to change maven and jdk version but it still doesn't work?

If you output the query using spring.jpa.show-sql: true then it is expected output, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate

There is no problem, you get exactly what you need to . The query with ? is send to the SQL database, which replaces them with the parameters send. This way the preparation can be done once and the query plan re-used (performance).
